# htaccess RewriteUrl parameters not checked

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite url:

```
mydomain.com/index.php -> mydomain.com
```

I tried to use:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem - using this url rewrite mydomain.com/index.php? (take a look at a question mark at the end) is redirected too. Need to rewrite url just for exact match of mydomain.com/index.php without nothing added at the end (parameters etc).

Complementary explanation:

**mydomain.com/index.php?abc** dont have to be rewritten

just **mydomain.com/index.php -> mydomain.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `RewriteCond` with `THE_REQUEST`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ shows error "We could not check this condition because the variable to check against is unknown." and with variable it doesnt have to be rewritten, just exact match mydomain.com/index.php has to be rewritten. Thats the problem!

Comment: Never ever test .htaccess rules on that website. It is only good for some basic rules but not all. Test it on your local Apache. I have tested it and it is working pretty well.

Comment: Yes, it seems thats working just perfect! Thanks